# Grid Layout group - Child's positions and sorting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scaling, grid-layout

Hey fellow programmers,

Firstly, i want to explain the purpose of my task, which is to create an interactable UI grid where the user can select whatever grid element he is interested in. (This is already done, using Grid Layout Group - see attached image)  [image]

The whole grid is supposed to represent a real-life-sized squared area, which I have from data, consisting of length and width. From data, I also have an event list, which contains certain real-life events and positional data (x,y) of each event. So when a user selects a grid elemental, I want it to represent all events that is equal to within that positional range.

**My idea:** is so far is to find a calculation method to get the size of the UI grid relative to the real life size. But i need a way to actually get the size of the grid (Not hardcoding). And then access and sort each child element, so if the element which has been clicked on the attached image, would equal to (0,0), (0,1) and (0,2), so i can loop through each child element

I know this is a messy explanation, but I hope it makes somekind of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the following calculations:

Given the `TotalWidth`, `TotalHeight` and `CellWidth`, `CellHeight` of your grid and a `Position` within `TotalWidth/TotalHeight`. Where TotalWidth is the X-Width of your grid, CellWidth the X-Width of your cells, Position the position within your grid.

```
CellIndexX = Position.X % (TotalWidth / CellWidth);
CellIndexY = Position.Y / (TotalHeight / CellHeight);
```

`TotalWidth / CellWidth` basically calculates the amount of Cells on the X-Axis, and the same happens for the amount of cells for the Y-Axis.

This should then allow you to get the cell by Index like:

```
int TotalWidth = 4000;
int TotalHeight = 2000;

int CellWidth = 20; // TotalWidth / CellWidth = 4000/20 = 200 grid tiles on the x-Axis
int CellHeight = 20; // TotalWidth / CellWidth = 4000/20 = 100 grid tiles on the y-Axis

Cell[,] myGrid;

Cell GetCellForPosition(Vector3 Position)
{
    CellIndexX = Position.X % (TotalWidth / CellWidth);
    CellIndexY = Position.Y / (TotalHeight / CellHeight);
    
    Cell result = myGrid[CellIndexY, CellIndexX];
    return result;
}
```

For the real world size versus the grid size, you can use the rule of three. Or more simplified, you just come up with a factor

If the RealWorldSize is: `120X meters * 90Y meters`

and you want the grid to be `100X` meters, your factor would be: `100/120 = 0.8333`, which you can then use to calculate the Y height of your grid by: `YGridHeight = 90 * 0.833 = 75;`